# how to check values of dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
d1 = {'name': 'Sagar','age': 25}    
d2 = {'name': 'Sassdr', 'age':122}    
d3 = {'name': 'Saga23weer', 'age':123344}    
d4 = {'name': '2133Sagar', 'age':14322}    
ch = input("Enter your value: ")
```

How can I search inputted value from these dictionaries?
and if found value then it returns Found else return not found.

Comment: what have you attempted

Comment: Yes Paul. I am want to search value not key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of dictionaries and search in it:

```
d1 = {'name': 'Sagar','age': 25}    
d2 = {'name': 'Sassdr', 'age':122}    
d3 = {'name': 'Saga23weer', 'age':123344}    
d4 = {'name': '2133Sagar', 'age':14322}
d = [d1,d2,d3,d4]

def check(ch):
    for entry in d:
        if entry["name"] == ch:
            return("found")
    return ("Not found")

while True:
    ch = input("Enter your value: ")
    if ch == "stop":
        break
    print(check(ch))
```

Output:

```
>>> 
Enter your value: Sagar
found
Enter your value: Someone
Not found
Enter your value: 2133Sagar
found
Enter your value: stop
```

Comment: If you found what you are looking for please mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 2):

Why are a search value in different dictionary rather than in one??

Try this

merge all dictionary in one

```
d5 = {**d1, **d2, **d3, **d4}
```

and then check

```
if ch in d5 .values():
    print "Found"
else:
    print "Not Found"
```

Comment: The merging works only if python version is >= 3.5. See https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Answer (score 0):

The effect you want is called *key swap*. This snippet is the implementation:

```
def keyswap(yourdict):
    cache = {}
    for i in yourdict.keys():
        cache[yourdict[i]] = i
    for i in cache.keys():
        yourdict[i] = cache[i]
    del cache
```

It keyswaps inplace.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

Python2

```
def IsFound():
    list_dict = [d1, d2, d3, d4]
    values_list = []
    for each in list_dict:
        values_list += each.values()

    ch = input('enter your value')
    if ch in values_list:
        return 'Found'
    else:
        return 'Not Found'
```

Python3

```
def IsFound():
    dict = {**d1, **d2, **d3, **d4}

    ch = input('enter your value')
    if ch in dict.values():
        return 'Found'
    else:
        return 'Not Found'
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to do:

1. get the values of dict;
2. search all dicts;
3. mark result as "Found" if matches.

for step 1:

```
dict.values()
```

for step 2:

there's many way to combine all dicts, as everybody gives.

you can pick all values first to set a new list, then search if your input matches like this:

```
# combine all dicts
d = d1.values() + d2.values() +d3.values() + d4.values()
# judge if matches
if ch in d:
    # do something
```

hope this code can release your confuse.